# My php login system works if i log in as a admin but not as a common user

Tags: php, authentication

I am doing a website as a class project, if i log as a admin user it works but if I log in as a normal user it doesn't logs me in but it keeps the cookies.

Here is the login php code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(isset($_POST['username'])){
require "config.php";
$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);
$contra =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
$consulta = $con->prepare("SELECT cod_usuario, Contra, id FROM Usuario WHERE cod_usuario = ?");
$consulta->bind_param("s",$usuario);
$consulta->execute();
$consulta->bind_result($username, $password, $id);
$consulta->store_result();

if($consulta->num_rows == 1){
    if($consulta->fetch()){
        if(password_verify($contra, $password)){
            session_start();
            session_name('login');
            if($usuario == 'aleaallee' || $usuario == 'administrator'){
                setcookie('loggeduser', $usuario, time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
                setcookie('token', $id, time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
                setcookie('admin', true, time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
                $_SESSION["username"] = $usuario;
                $consulta->close();
                header('location: index.php');
            }else{
                setcookie('loggeduser', $usuario, time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
                setcookie('token', $id, time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
                $_SESSION["username"] = $usuario;
                $consulta->close();
                header('location: index.php');
            }
        }else{
            echo "<h1>Password doesn't match</h1>";
            $consulta->close();
            header('location: index.php');
        }
    }
}
```

}

I know that the code is probably not good in terms of security but I just wanted to do a quick login system.

EDIT: It seems the code tells me that the passwords doesn't match.

Here is the code I used for the register function:

```
function register($name, $lastname, $user, $pass, $repeated_password, $mail, $birthdate, $location, $address){
require "config.php";
$con = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $dbname);
if($pass == $repeated_password){
    $cryptpassword = password_hash(trim($password), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $id = bin2hex(random_bytes(8));
    $consulta = "INSERT INTO Usuario VALUES('$user', '$name', '$lastname', '$cryptpassword', '$mail', '$address', '$birthdate', '$location', '$id');";
    mysqli_query($con, $consulta);
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

}

Comment: You must not use both, `mysqli_real_escape_string` _and_ parameter binding. That will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't combine mysqli_real_escape_string with prepared statements as them are already escaped in bind_param. For the rest of the code it should work, try adding some echoes to know which part of the code reaches in each login test.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, sorry. It should have been a comment maybe.

Comment: I know, but I don't have the necessary reputation to do it.